# Shutdown or Restart Computer from WCF Service Not Working

Tags: wcf, acl, wcfserviceclient

I have a function in a WCF service hosted in IIS 7.5 which it task is shutdown or restart computer when it is being called.

I use the built in command line and execute it by passing "shutdown.exe -t 0 -r" to restart or "shutdown.exe -t 0 -s" to shutdown.

```
    Try
        Using process As New System.Diagnostics.Process()
            Dim startInfo As New System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo()
            With startInfo
                .WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
                .CreateNoWindow = True
                .UseShellExecute = False
                .RedirectStandardError = True
                .RedirectStandardInput = True
                .RedirectStandardOutput = True
                .FileName = "shutdown.exe"
                .Arguments = "-t 0 -r"
            End With
            If System.Environment.OSVersion.Version.Major >= 6 Then process.StartInfo.Verb = "runas"
            process.StartInfo = startInfo
            process.Start()
            process.WaitForExit()
            If process.ExitCode = 0 Then
                Return True
            Else
                Return False
            End If
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        Return False
    End Try
```

The command line works fine if execute in command prompt manually. However it doesn't work when it is being execute inside WCF service.

Comment: What identity is the WCF service running as? You might also want to add `-f` to the arguments.

Comment: The wcf application pool run as localsystem. What is -f parameter?

Comment: It forces running applications to close: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491003.aspx

Comment: @slugster It still doesn't work. I thought by using localsystem identity we will have all administrator privileges. But it seems it is not how it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, trying everything and keep failed, and ended up on [this guy who use bat file](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/yuanwang200409/RemoteRestartWindows09252006141003PM/RemoteRestartWindows.aspx). And it works..!

It is so weird and still don't know why it works. For now...who cares :)...later when I have spare time I will try to figure it out.

```
        ....
        Dim strCmd As String = "SHUTDOWN -m {0} -f -t 0 -r"           
        File.WriteAllText(_pathCmd & "cmd_restart.bat", String.Format(strCmd, "127.0.0.1"))
        Return ExecuteCommand(_pathCmd & "cmd_restart.bat", "")
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess that your service doesn't have permission to shutdown pc (I guess user that owes permission is network user and can't do this). [Check out Event Log for details](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/open-event-viewer#1TC=windows-7), I am pretty sure it contains answer on your question.

Check out [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21492023/impersonate-wcf-service-to-run-under-a-specific-domain-accounthosted-on-iis) how to run wcf service under specific account.

Comment: I tried to run the process with provide specific administrator credential. Then I get 4 new event log saying: 1. A logon was attempted using explicit credentials. 2. An account was successfully log on. 3. Special previledge assigned to new log on. 4. An account was logged off.

Comment: But nothing happen. No restart, no shutdown. Nothing.